# How to get count of keys pressed on the keyboard in an minute? ( using python )

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

Actually I am trying to build a monitoring system that returns the total count of keystrokes made by the keyboard in a minute. The output should be an integer that holds the value of the number of keystrokes by a person in a minute? ( in python )

Answer (score 2):

This should kinda do the trick... It's not the most efficient / precise but I believe it works.

```
import sys
import tty
import time

# Disable newline buffering on stdin
tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())

seconds = 60

keys = []
while x := sys.stdin.read(1):
    now = time.time()
    keys.append((now, x))

    # Filter out old keys
    keys = [(timestamp, key) for timestamp, key in keys if timestamp > now - seconds]

    if keys:
        # Calculate how many seconds our current list spans
        timestamps = [timestamp for timestamp, _key in keys]
        total = max(timestamps) - min(timestamps)
          
        # Wait until at-least 1 second passed before showing results
        if total > 1:
            keys_per_second = len(keys) / total
            print(keys_per_second * seconds)
```

Or a Python<3.8 friendly version:

```
import sys
import tty
import time

# Disable newline buffering on stdin
tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())

seconds = 60

keys = []
x = sys.stdin.read(1)
while x:
    now = time.time()
    keys.append((now, x))

    # Filter out old keys
    keys = [(timestamp, key) for timestamp, key in keys if timestamp > now - seconds]

    if keys:
        # Calculate how many seconds our current list spans
        timestamps = [timestamp for timestamp, _key in keys]
        total = max(timestamps) - min(timestamps)
          
        # Wait until at-least 1 second passed before showing results
        if total > 1:
            keys_per_second = len(keys) / total
            print(keys_per_second * seconds)

    x = sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I get an error on executing the above code; @Omer @ Omer

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-7-15be3d712170>", line 6, in <module>
tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tty.py", line 32, in setcbreak
mode = tcgetattr(fd)
error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')

Comment: What OS / terminal / shell are you using?

Comment: This is a limitation of the Spyder console, try running the code in a regular console

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine in the normal console, but I do not get anything printed like the number of keystrokes pressed in 1 minute. @Omer

Comment: Trying pressing on keys for more than a second. It doesn't display anything in the first second of pressing. The extrapolated keys-per-minute should appear for every key you press. (If you press on 2 keys every second, it will display ~120, because 2 keys every second are 120 keys every minute)

Comment: Is that a problem with the way I am executing or something needs to be changed?

Comment: Put the code in a `.py` file, run it, keep pressing on keys for at-least 2 seconds (even if you don't see anything). Do numbers eventually appear?

Comment: Ok buddy! I know that it was just that i couldn't understand that what do these numbers signify(as i was getting numbers like 560,800), Please correct me if I am wrong, so this code would give me an expected number of keypresses in a minute after each keypress?@Omer

Comment: Yes. You mean 560 and 800, or 560800? If you see 560 and 800 it's reasonable. If you see 560800, something is completely wrong.

Comment: Buddy, I got 1200 as my first output, then it fell to 500, then to 200 as I reduced my typing speed. So it seems to work fine, thanks a lot brother! It was a great conversation with you! This was even better than the output I was expecting( which would be more helpful for my project). Thanks a lot again!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use pygame [library](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/) to track the count of any specific key

```
import pygame
count = 0
for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
     if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        count = count + 1
```

you can also use simple way

```
import msvcrt 
count = 0
while True:
  s = msvcrt.getch()
  if(s == 'q'):
     break
  else:
     count = count + 1
     print(count)
```

This will keep on counting you keystrokes until you press 'q'

Comment: thanks for your help, but i am getting the following error:

Comment: pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-1349d957963a>", line 3, in <module>
    for event in pygame.event.get():

error: video system not initialized

Answer (score 0):

```
from pynput import keyboard

c=0
with keyboard.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        if event.key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            break
        elif (str(event)) == "Press(key='1')":
                c+=1
                print(c)
```

Use any keys inside "Press(key='1')" like "Press(key='2')", "Press(key='t')", to get counts

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it doesn't account for the sixty second limit. Also they don't care which specific key is pressed. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to try to answer what was asked.

Comment: Please fix the answer to match with the question's requirement.